# Is it possible to access the DOM of a website through a URL with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I understand that to access the DOM (document object Model) of a website through javascript you must use the Chrome console while on the website .. But what if I need to access the DOM of that same website but from an external document with extension .js or .html?

How can I access the DOM of a website without using the browser console?

Comment: You need a parallel or nested browsing context, i.e. a pop-up window or an iframe element where to load the document to retrieve the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

If the site does not have CORS restrictions, or if you're trying to connecting to a page *from* a page on the same origin, it's possible. Once you have the response text (which you can get with `fetch` or XMLHttpRequest), you can turn it into a document with `DOMParser`, and then you can navigate through it using DOM methods like `querySelector`:

```js
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/example.com/')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
    const h1 = doc.querySelector('h1');
    console.log(h1.textContent);
  });
```