# Can I access elements from a web page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot in JavaScript and implementing a feature where when you ask a coding question it gives you a snippet. I'm using [Grepper](https://www.codegrepper.com) and returning the url with the search results. For example:
[Hello World in JavaScript Search Results](https://www.codegrepper.com/search.php?answer_removed=1&q=hello%20world%20javascript). I would like to access the div containing the snippet. Is this possible? And how would I do it?

Here's my code:

```
if (message.startsWith('programming')) {
    // Command = programming
    message = message.replace('programming ', ''); // Remove programming from the string
    message = encodeURIComponent(message) // Encode the string for a url
    msg.channel.send(`https://www.codegrepper.com/search.php?answer_removed=1&q=${message}`); // Place formatted string into url and send it to the discord server
    
    // Here the program should access the element containing the snippet instead of sending the url:

}
```

I'm new to JavaScript so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

Comment: I know how to do that but how would I go about accessing the elements from another link? I need to get an element from an external website. Thanks.

Comment: oh .. may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073160/is-it-possible-to-access-the-dom-of-a-website-through-a-url-with-javascript) could help you then ..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the API you are using returns HTML/Text data, not JSON, Grepper has a lot more APIs if you just look into them, you can instead use this API that returns JSON data. If you need more information you can check [**this**](https://github.com/jareer12/code-grepper) Unofficial List of Grepper APIs

```yaml
https://www.codegrepper.com/api/get_answers_1.php?v=2&s=${SearchQuery}&u=98467
```

**How Do I Access the div containing the snippet?**
To access the div you might need to use python web scraping to **scrape** the `innerHTML` of the div but I think it's easier to use the other API.

Or

You can put `/api/` in the url like:

```yaml
https://www.codegrepper.com/api/search.php?answer_removed=1&q=js%20loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for this is to send a GET request to the underlying API

```
https://www.codegrepper.com/api/search.php?q=hello%20world%20javascript&search_options=search_titles
```

This will return the answers in JSON format. Obviously you'd have to adjust the parameters.

**How did I find out about this?**

Simply look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools while loading the page. You'll see a GET request being sent out to the endpoint, returning mentioned answers as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the grepper api.

#### Install node-fetch

`npm i node-fetch`, You need this package for making requestes to the api.
To import It in the code just type:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

#### Write this code

Modify your code like this:

```js
if (message.startsWith('programming')) {
    message = message.replace('programming ', '');
    message = encodeURIComponent(message)
    
    // Making the request
    fetch(`https://www.codegrepper.com/api/search.php?answer_removed=1&q=${message}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        // response is a json object containing all the data You need
        // now You need to parse this data
        const answers = response.answers; // this is an array of objects
        const answers_limit = 3; // set a limit for the answers
        
        // cheking if there is any answer
        if(answers.length == 0) {
            return msg.channel.send("No answers were found!");
        }

        // creating the embed
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Here the answers to your question!")
            .setDescription("")
        
        // parsing
        for(let i = 0; i < answers_limit; i++) {
            if(answers[i]) {
                embed.description += `**${i+1}° answer**:\n\`\`\`js\n${answers[i].answer}\`\`\`\n`;
            }
        }
        console.log(embed)

        msg.channel.send(embed);
    });
        
}
```

[image: This is the output]